# caret: "Some row.names duplicated" warning when using RFE

Tags: r, svm, r-caret, statistics-bootstrap, rfe

I am building a toy dataset based on the linear problem from page 5 from this [paper](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/M.Pontil/reading/featsel.pdf) in order to test feature selection using caret's RFE+SVM with rbf kernel. However, when RFE finishes, I get a warning per bootstrap iteration with the following message: "In data.row.names(row.names, rowsi, i) : some row.names duplicated:" followed by many row numbers, until the output is truncated.

Is this caused because the bootstrap may be selecting samples with replacement and therefore duplicating rows in the bootstrapped data, or is there something else wrong with this? Any advice appreciated (please forgive the lazy implementation of the artificial dataset).

```
library(caret)

################
# 1. Building dataset
################
set.seed(1)
n.samples <- 500
y <- round(runif(n = n.samples, min=0, max=1))
data <- matrix(nrow=n.samples, ncol=202)

for(i in 1:n.samples){
  toss <- runif(n=1, min=0, max=1)
  if(toss <= 0.7) {
    for(j in 1:3){
      data[i,j] <- y[i]*rnorm(n = 1, mean = i, sd = 1)
    }

    for(j in 4:6){
      data[i,j] <- rnorm(n = 1, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    }
  } else {
    for(j in 1:3){
      data[i,j] <- rnorm(n=1, mean=0, sd=1)
    }

    for(j in 4:6){
      data[i,j] <- y[i]*rnorm(n=1, mean=i-3, sd = 1) 
    }
  }

  for(j in 7:202){
    data[i,j] <- rnorm(n = 1, mean = 0, sd = 20)
  }
}

colnames(data) <- c(paste("s", 1:6, sep = ""), paste('ns', 7:202, sep=''))
rownames(data) <- paste('sample', 1:n.samples, sep='')

################
# 2. Perform SVM - RFE
################
set.seed(1)

rfe.control.settings <- rfeControl(functions = caretFuncs,
                                   method = 'boot',
                                   number = 30,
                                   verbose = TRUE)

svm.fit <- rfe(x=data, 
               y=y,
               sizes=c(1,2,3,4),
               rfeControl = rfe.control.settings,
               method = 'svmRadial') #passing options to train / caretFuncs
```

Comment: I have the same problem using linearSVM method in combination with bootstraping. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, and what fixed it for me is changing the data class from `matrix` to `data.frame`.